# Производительность/скорость браузера для элементов дизайна.

Tags: css3, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте. 
Вопрос такой: 
*Когда производительность браузера будет лучше*:

1. Элементы панелей и кнопок отрисовываются при помощи CSS3 (градиенты, закругления и др.);
2. Рисунок, который весит 3-5KB (если для кнопки, то один рисунок для кнопки нажатой и кнопки не нажатой).

И еще, на сколько отличается производительность? Т.е. вопрос, в принципе, звучит еще и так: *имеет ли большой вес разница между способом "1" и способом "2"?*

PS
Для тех, кому станет интересно, почему меня волнует данный вопрос: приложение для мобильных телефонов.

Comment: Интересный вопрос! Думаю, что лучше всего сделать два страницы и потестить.

Кстати, вместо второго способа правильнее будет использовать метод спрайтов, т.е. грузить одно большое изображение, вместо кучи маленьких. Это как минимум снизит нагрузку на сервер. Да и браузеру, скорее всего будет легче работать с одной картинкой, позиционируя её, чем держать кучу ресурсов в памяти, ИМХО.

Comment: Да. Надо еще вопрос поставить, как тестировать скорость браузера.

Comment: Не силен в данном вопросе, но, чисто для себя поинтересуюсь: а мобильные браузеры нормально относятся к CSS3 на данный момент?

Comment: Смотря какие, если брать браузеры под Android, iOS и WindowsMobile, то нормально, они почти полнофункциональные, на многих даже flash есть. А если обычные java, то не думаю, что стоит на них вообще ориентироваться.

Comment: Андроид 2+ ,
iPhone (по-моему, с 3-го),
Blackberry (не знаю, с какой версии ОС).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рассмотрим высококлассный пользовательский интерфейс. Допустим для элементов button будут прописаны свои правила active, hover и focus + естественно стили самой кнопки. Вопрос я прочитал(о том что картинка одна) но стараюсь дать максимально общий ответ

Допустим мы используем изображения: есть большая вероятность что нам захочется для каждого состояния захочется использовать свое изображение, а изображение это запрос на сервер, при этом без плясок с бубном, при первой загрузке страницы кнопка на каждом состоянии будет мигать (пока не прийдет ответ от сервера), что уже не очень красиво. Ну и естественно - +3 запроса на сервер(что не столь существенно, но тем не менее). Плюсы данного подхода в том что вы всегда получите именно такое отображение какое вы нарисуете (с точностью до пикселя), при использовании css3 *иногда* отображение будет *немного* отличатся.

Что касается описания кнопок средствами css: как только страница загружена все состояния кнопки полноценны не зависимо от того первое это посещение страницы или нет, что ИМХО довольно важно. Еще один плюс в том что вы можете повторно использовать прописаные вами правила (и для этих кнопок ситуация будет точно такой-же). Ну и, естественно - нет никаких запросов на сервер.

По поводу именно производительности - немного производительнее(обычно) будет css потому-что компиляция css очень и очень быстра во всех без исключения моб.браузерах + нет необходимости тянуть картинки с сервера. Хотя, откровенно говоря, прирост будет незначительным.

Теперь о вашей ситуации - выбирайте по ситуации в зависимости от ваших потребностей.

Если речь о разработке под моб.устройства лично я бы выбрал вариант с css. Да и, если использовать css - мы без проблем может написать правила состояний кнопки, таким образом мы можем улучшить пользовательский интерфейс и, значительно, не потерять в производительности.
Еще хотел бы добавить немаловажный пункт - *возможность очень быстро изменить текущее отображение кнопок*, если речь идет о картинках - приходится *перерисовывать* картинку, что ИМХО - очень и очень не удобно и, лично меня, жестко напрягает.

Вообщем именно по скорости и производительности разницы не будет.(вернее ею можно принебречь ибо это, скорее, похоже на псевдо-оптимизацию или нано-оптимизацию)

Comment: Спрайты - это считать танцами с бубном?! Странно, я всегда их считал быстрым и элегантным решением мигающих кнопок. =/

Comment: Какбы да - это танцы с бубном =) 

Я не говорил что это плохое решение, но тем не менее.

Лично для меня главным фактором в выборе того или иного решения является то что изображения нужно перерисовывать, с css все намного проще

Comment: Ого! Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Учитывая скоростные характеристики мобильного интернета, то ИМХО лучший вариант - css, в любом случае текст будет меньше весить чем графика, еще плюс - нет лишнего запроса на сервер, еще плюс - нет лишней нагрузки (хоть и мизерной) на сервер, ну а минус - заморочка с кроссбраузерностью!

Comment: Там везде, кроме виндовс-мобайл, стоит движок webkit, так что никакой кроссбраузерности :)

Comment: кроссбраузерностью?)) мы же про мобилы говорим =)

Comment: Да что вы пристали, не секу я в мобильном WEBе =) Я думал в мобильникак так же как и на ОСях.

Answer (score 1):

не думаю что эта разница сэкономит тебе производительность и скорость работы. Как мне кажется, способ один - хорош тем, что прорисовка происходит на стороне клиента и поэтому экономится трафик, а 2й способ - хорош тем, что картинка не изменится при любом браузере и его возможностями работы с CSS3

Comment: Спасибо за мнение. Посмотрим, что скажут остальные, или согласятся с вами, поставив плюс.

Comment: Картинка конечно хороша, но я Вам не завидую, если заказчик захочет например, сменить оттенок сайта ;) 

Думаю лучше потратить немного времени на кроссбраузерный CSS, чем потом перерисовывать весь дизайн.

Comment: @invincible , спасибо, хороший совет. Но вопрос стоит в производительности. Это превыше всего. Ну и скорость выполнения работы тоже.

Comment: сложно тебе на такое ответить, потому что если у тебя процессор(100% это производительности) простаивает, а ты его загрузишь на 2% или 25%, ты все равно не заметишь этих тормозов, да и сейчас такое время, что проблема "такого масштаба" неактуальна

Answer (score 1):

Вот нарыл как раз то, что искали: [Тест производительности](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/04/21/css3-vs-css-a-speed-benchmark/)

CSS3 оказался чуть пошустрее. Хотя там не использовалась технология спрайтов, которая значительно уменьшает количество и время запроса к серверу.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду изучать.